# How to politely ask for clarification on a person's designation?

Tags: phrases, formality, conversation

This is a dilemma I always face when talking with people. When some people introduce themselves they would just say

> Hello, I'm Martin and I'm an executive of ABC Company

There are so many varieties of executives (marketing executive, chief executive etc). What would be the most polite way to ask such person what type of executive

Comment: The executive of a company normally means the Chief Executive Officier.

Comment: @sotondolphin thanks. But there are occasions I'm sure that that person is not a CEO of the company. That person is just using the word to give unnecessary gravity to the designation!

Comment: you can ask" Could you please be more specific on your official designation?  "

Comment: Would you mind to be more specific on your official designation?

Comment: @sotondolphin I think large companies have many executives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a business situation I would offer my business card and politely ask:

> "Do you have a card I could have?"

Usually the information you seek is written on the card. This avoids the embarrassment of interrogating someone rather important and also showing your ignorance of their business or one's own lack of research or poor briefing on the meeting.

At executive level they would expect to be known.

Conversely, if you are important enough you could get away with asking anything!

Comment: +1 for _'At executive level they would expect to be known.'_, which is a very valid point. You do not want to spur their ego.

Comment: @briantompsett thanks a lot. I think it is a very diplomatic approach!